# Where does one go to get security alert notifications?

Tags: java, security, mailing-list

At my company, we are trying to stay abreast of security alerts and notifications in a more consistent fashion.  We are using a large number of Java libraries for our projects, and would like to be notified if there are security updates for those libraries.  I have spent some time trying to find security lists, but to no avail.  This could be because I do not know the proper search terms (possible), or because I don't know where to look (also possible).  It could also be because they don't exist.

The types of Libraries are things like Jetty, Hibernate, some of the Apache group, and the like.  Does anyone know if there is a centralized place for these alerts to collect?  Are there groups that specifically focus on sending out security alerts that are noticed in different products?  I am pretty new at looking for this stuff, and not really sure where to go at this point.

Comment: I used to be subscribed to one of such alert lists via RSS (it was a site) but as I have dropped subscription long time ago, I don't have an address. But such site/list does exist (if this helps you :)

Comment: Check maybe this (http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1) helps you to some extent.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp wish you had made that an answer so I could upvote it - thanks.  :)

Comment: Just to add: A key word that is handy to know when searching for security alerts is "[advisories](https://www.google.com/search?q=advisories)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most vulnerabilities tend to get announced on mailing lists like the [Bugtraq](http://seclists.org/bugtraq/) which is hosted by SecurityFocus. You'll find a separate mailing list for [Open Source projects](http://seclists.org/oss-sec/), although most vulnerabilities aren't discussed here, and neither are a lot of disclosures.

You'll also find [MITRE-CVE](http://cve.mitre.org/) and [OSVDB](http://osvdb.org/) as useful sources. So is the case with your country's CERT, although in most cases you'll find that the alerts issued by [US-CERT](http://www.us-cert.gov/cas/techalerts/) are sufficient enough to follow.

Comment: Again, Thank You.  You gave me the places to start looking, and it looks like (at least for now) these will suffice, rather than having to subscribe to a bunch of different mailing lists.

Comment: @aperkins, Well, if it helps you, these were sufficient in my previous job where the alerts regarding JREs and few other FOSS projects were important, although I didn't have the burden of looking for vulnerabilities in huge projects like Spring and Hibernate.